# Which one is correct, "prime period" , "medrian period", "heyday"?

Tags: phrases

For example, Tang dynasty was "prime period" or "medirian period" or "heyday" in China. At that time, China's had many number ones in the world.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "medirian period".

Comment: @NathanTuggy Probably *meridian*.

Comment: "Golden age" is common - implying general prosperity and artistic/scientific achievement.

Comment: Sorry, a typo, should be meridian

Comment: @Jokaec: "Meridian" doesn't fit at all, for the reasons GalacticCowboy gave. (Also, you can [edit] to fix typos.)

Answer (score 3):

To a large extent, this depends on your context - formal or informal. "Heyday" is quite informal, and would not be appropriate for a scholarly audience, for example.

"Medirian" appears to be a misspelling of "meridian", which has little to do with this concept. "Prime meridian" is a geographic term referring to an east-west position (longitude) from which other positions are measured. Examples would be the center of a city, the Greenwich meridian, etc. You might make the case that this term could be used as a simile - that the Tang dynasty was a period by which all others are measured - but this meaning may not be immediately obvious to your readers.

"Prime" would be appropriate in a formal context, though you would normally prefix it with an article such as "the" or "a", depending on your intended meaning.

As pointed out by @Adam, another common idiomatic description of such a time period is "Golden Age". This describes a time period of great prosperity and/or achievements within a culture or within a particular field.